# interpolate annual to monthly & then change long data to wide, R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a large csv data file, sample of the data as below.

```
name                  year            value
China                 1997            481970
Japan                 1997            8491480
Germany               1997            4678022
China                 1998            589759
Japan                 1998            7912546
Germany               1998            5426582
```

After several attempts with no success, I would like to interpolate my data to monthly, and then change the format of data to be as in the example below,

```
date             China       Japan        Germany       
1997-01-31       40164.17    707623.33    389835.17
1997-02-28       80328.33    1415246.67   779670.33
1997-03-30       1204925     2122870      1169505.50
1997-04-30       160656.67   2830493.33   1559340.67  
1997-05-31       200820.83   3538116.67   1949175.83
    .               .           .              .
    .               .           .              .
    .               .           .              .
1997-12-31       481970       8491480      4678022

1998-01-31       49146.58     659378.83    452215.17
1998-02-28       98293.17     1318757.67   904430.33
1998-03-30       147439.75    1978136.5    1356645.5 
1998-04-30       196586.33    2637515.33   1808860.67
1998-05-31       245732.97    3296894.17   2261075.83
    .               .           .              .
    .               .           .              .
    .               .           .              .
1998-12-31        589759      7912546      5426582
```

someone suggested this [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) though it proved hard for me to reach the desired results. Maybe I'm not that good in python.

I would like to do it in R.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input shown reproducibly in the Note at the end convert it to a zoo object `z` which, by specifying `split=`, will also convert it to wide form at the same time.  Then expand it using `merge` and use linear interpolation with `na.approx`.  Alternately replace `na.approx` with `na.spline`.  Finally convert the time index to `Date` class. The result is a zoo object `m`.  If you need a data frame use `fortify.zoo(m)`.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, split = 1, index = 2, FUN = as.numeric)

m <- na.approx(merge(z, zoo(, c(kronecker(time(z), 0:11/12, "+")))))
time(m) <- as.Date(as.yearmon(time(m)), frac = 1)
m
```

giving:

```
              China Germany   Japan
1997-01-31 481970.0 4678022 8491480
1997-02-28 490952.4 4740402 8443236
1997-03-31 499934.8 4802782 8394991
1997-04-30 508917.2 4865162 8346747
1997-05-31 517899.7 4927542 8298502
1997-06-30 526882.1 4989922 8250257
1997-07-31 535864.5 5052302 8202013
1997-08-31 544846.9 5114682 8153769
1997-09-30 553829.3 5177062 8105524
1997-10-31 562811.8 5239442 8057280
1997-11-30 571794.2 5301822 8009035
1997-12-31 580776.6 5364202 7960790
1998-01-31 589759.0 5426582 7912546
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "name                  year            value
China                 1997            481970
Japan                 1997            8491480
Germany               1997            4678022
China                 1998            589759
Japan                 1998            7912546
Germany               1998            5426582"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
DT[, date := as.IDate(paste0(year, "-12-31"))][,
    c("y0", "y1") := .(value, shift(value, -1L, fill=value[.N])), name]

longDT <- DT[, {
    eom <- seq(min(date)+1L, max(date)+1L, by="1 month") - 1L
    v <- unlist(mapply(function(a, d) a + (0:11) * d, y0, (y1 - y0)/12, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
    .(eom, v=v[seq_along(eom)])
}, name]

dcast(longDT, eom ~ name, sum, value.var="v")
```

output:

```
           eom     China   Germany     Japan
 1: 1996-12-31  40164.17  389835.2  707623.3
 2: 1997-01-31  76981.32  747184.1 1356278.1
 3: 1997-02-28 113798.48 1104533.0 2004932.8
 4: 1997-03-31 150615.63 1461881.9 2653587.5
 5: 1997-04-30 187432.78 1819230.8 3302242.2
 6: 1997-05-31 224249.93 2176579.7 3950896.9
 7: 1997-06-30 261067.09 2533928.6 4599551.7
 8: 1997-07-31 297884.24 2891277.5 5248206.4
 9: 1997-08-31 334701.39 3248626.4 5896861.1
10: 1997-09-30 371518.54 3605975.3 6545515.8
11: 1997-10-31 408335.70 3963324.2 7194170.6
12: 1997-11-30 445152.85 4320673.1 7842825.3
13: 1997-12-31 481970.00 4678022.0 8491480.0
14: 1998-01-31 490952.42 4740402.0 8443235.5
15: 1998-02-28 499934.83 4802782.0 8394991.0
16: 1998-03-31 508917.25 4865162.0 8346746.5
17: 1998-04-30 517899.67 4927542.0 8298502.0
18: 1998-05-31 526882.08 4989922.0 8250257.5
19: 1998-06-30 535864.50 5052302.0 8202013.0
20: 1998-07-31 544846.92 5114682.0 8153768.5
21: 1998-08-31 553829.33 5177062.0 8105524.0
22: 1998-09-30 562811.75 5239442.0 8057279.5
23: 1998-10-31 571794.17 5301822.0 8009035.0
24: 1998-11-30 580776.58 5364202.0 7960790.5
25: 1998-12-31 589759.00 5426582.0 7912546.0
           eom     China   Germany     Japan
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("name     year            value
China                 1996            40164.17
Japan                 1996            707623.33
Germany               1996            389835.17
China                 1997            481970
Japan                 1997            8491480
Germany               1997            4678022
China                 1998            589759
Japan                 1998            7912546
Germany               1998            5426582")
```

I have taken the liberty to add in the data for 1996.